# Inconsistent Behavior in SOA Composite/BPEL

Tags: debugging, soa, bpel

I'm working on a BPEL process that includes an email service, and is generally kicked off by an AQ Adapter. The composite pulls email addresses from a DVM lookup and from the content returned by a service invoke.

My code that assigns the email addresses looks something like this:

```
concat(bpws:getVariableData('EmailVariable'),',',bpws:getVariableData('ServiceOutputVariable, 'ServiceVariablePart','Email')
```

Where "EmailVariable," is two comma separated addresses and "Email," is a single email address

When BPEL is called via the AQ Adapter, the "to" line of the email comes back as EmailA,EmailBEmailC.

When I wired it to a file adapter for debugging, though, the "to" line reads "EmailA,EmailB,EmailC" (The desired result, obviously).

The only thing that changed from the AQ adapter version to the File Adapter version is the source of the kickoff value.

What could be causing this inconsistent behavior?

Comment: Hi. Is this Bpel 2.0, 11g?

Comment: This is BPEL 1.1, 11g

Comment: Hey. Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: I implemented a workaround by putting the third email address in the CC line, but I'd still like to know if the original approach didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious first question is have you posted this in  the [Oracle SOA forum](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=320) or searched oracle.support to see if it is a bug?
Anyway, put a mediator between the AQ interface and BPEL and have the mediator resolve the issue, through data transformation, which is its purpose in the first place and best practice design pattern: isolate your service implementation from the service interface.

Comment: I wasn't able to turn up anything on either the SOA Forum or support. Unfortunately, I've been tasked with making the email service work without making major changes to the rest of the composite (Which was designed by someone else. At this point I have as solution, but I'd still like to know *why* this is happening